# Как реализовать прозрачность блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, scss

[image: прозрачность блока по краям и в нижних углах]

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать вот такую прозрачность по краям блока и в нижних углах?**

*Работаю с самого утра, вот дошёл до этого блока и голова уже забита.*

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста поконкретней вопрос, вам необходимо создать внутреннюю тень по краям картинки или только нижний край?

Comment: по краям, но с низу больше чем на других краях

Comment: Покажите ваши текущие стили для данного элемента

Comment: Желательно знать точные цифры размера размытия тени по краям, ниже представил пример стилей как это можно выполнить, думаю из этого примера получиться настроить код согласно техническому заданию

Answer (score 1):

Тени вокруг изображения внутри блока

```css
 .block {
            width: 300px;
            /* Задайте желаемую ширину блока */
            height: 100%;
            /* Задайте желаемую высоту блока */
            position: relative;
            /* Устанавливаем позицию в "relative", чтобы тень была видна внутри блока */
        }

        .block img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            /* Здесь можно настроить способ масштабирования изображения, чтобы оно заполнило блок */
        }

        .block::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 68px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            /* Здесь 10px 10px 68px 0px определяет размер и размытие тени, а rgba(255,255,255,0.3) задает цвет и уровень прозрачности */
        }
```

```html
<div class="block">
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHVzU.png" alt="Изображение">
</div>
```

Comment: дело в том что блок это не одна картинка.
этот блок анимированый кружочки внутри двигаются в разные стороны по вертикали и обратно
Я бы скинул сюда HTML и CSS но столько много нельзя в коментарий.

Comment: Лучше текст технического задания напишите, так как не до конца понятно что вы хотите сделать

Comment: Всё, разобрался))
Спасибо за наводку)))

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что у Вас вышло разобраться в этой задаче!)))